# ReportViewer - Click Through Report - display issue

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, report-viewer2012

I have a Report with a hyperlink column (total count) that links to another report (detail, "click through" Report). The main report displays fine, with all the columns, but when I click on a link in the hyperlink column, it opens up another report, in the same window, which does not display correctly. It is aligned to the right, with about 400px width (it does not fill out the total 100% width of the ReportViewer, and I don't know where the 400px comes from) and the page footer div overlaps it (footer should be on the bottom of the page).

I am using ReportViewer 11. This is the ReportViewer settings:

```
<div style="width: auto; height: 100%;">
    <center>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ZoomMode="PageWidth" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
            BackColor="#F8F8F8" ShowPrintButton="true"
            AsyncRendering="False" SizeToReportContent="True" ProcessingMode="Remote" ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowToolBar="True"
            ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowZoomControl="False">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </center>
</div>
```

I wanted it to display correctly, like the main report. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the Height and Width properties solved the problem:

```
Height="100%" Width="100%"
```